# Show that series converge or diverge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converge and has positive terms then decide if following series converge or diverge :

a) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cdot \sin{a_n}$

I think it converge since $\sin {a_n} \le 1$ so $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cdot \sin{a_n} \le \sum_{n} ^{\infty} a_n$ but I don't know if it's true.

b) $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n} \cdot \frac{n^{a_n}-1}{\ln{n}} $

here I have idea to use the fact that $\displaystyle \lim_{a_n \to 0}\frac{n^{a_n}-1}{a_n}= \ln{n}$ and we will have

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cdot \sqrt{a_n} \cdot \frac{n^{a_n}-1}{a_n \cdot \ln{n}} \to \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cdot \sqrt{a_n}$ and we know it converge .

Comment: For a), you need to take absolute values ($|a_n\sin a_n|\le|a_n|$).

Comment: OK, but why it's neccesery I show then the series converge absolutely?

Comment: Because having $a_n\le b_n$ and $\sum b_n$ convergent does not imply $\sum a_n$ converges (take $b_n=0$, $a_n=-1$). (I may have misunderstood your comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

For a) $\displaystyle  |a_n\sin a_n|\le|a_n|$ implies $\displaystyle  \sum a_n\sin a_n$ is absolutely convergent, thus is convergent.

For b), we have two separate cases.

b.1) Assume $a_n \ln n \rightarrow 0$, then we have  $$   \sqrt{a_n} \: \frac{n^{a_n}-1}{\ln{n}} \sim a_n^{3/2}. \tag1$$ Now, as $n$ is sufficiently great, since $a_n$ tends to $0$, we have $a_n^{3/2}\leq C a_n$ for some constant $C$, implying the convergence of $\displaystyle  \sum a_n^{3/2}$, thus the convergence of $\displaystyle  \sum \sqrt{a_n}  \:\frac{n^{a_n}-1}{\ln{n}} $.

b.2) Assume that we **don't** have $a_n \ln n \rightarrow 0$, then the series  $\displaystyle  \sum \sqrt{a_n}  \:\frac{n^{a_n}-1}{\ln{n}}$ might be divergent, as **Kelenner** proved below, or it might be convergent as **Jonas Meyer** has proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078516/is-this-series-sum-n-geq-2-sqrta-n-fracna-n-1-ln-n-always-diverge).

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but if you take $a_n=0$ if $n\not =2^{k^3}$, and $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{k^2}$ for $n=2^{k^3}$, then the series $a_n$ is convergent, but for $n=2^{k^3}$, we get $\displaystyle b_n=\sqrt{a_n}\frac{n^{a_n}-1}{\log n}=\frac{2^k-1}{k^4\log 2}$, and hence the series $b_n$ is divergent.

Comment: I think that in my example, you can replace $a_n=0$ by say $a_n=1/n!$ if $n\not =2^{k^3}$, and the conclusion remain the same: the series $a_n$ is convergent, and the series $b_n$ is divergent. So the fact that $a_n>0$ is not the point.

Comment: @Kelenner We must have $a_n \ln n→0$ in $(1)$. This was the point. Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think that your proof works fine now.