# Is this series $\sum_{n \geq 2}\sqrt{a_n}\frac{n^{a_n}-1}{\ln n}$ always divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Let $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ be a series with **positive terms** which is a **convergent series** and suppose that we **don't have** $\displaystyle a_n \ln n \rightarrow 0$.

Is the following series **always divergent**?
$$ B=\displaystyle  \sum_{n \geq 2} \sqrt{a_n}  \:\frac{n^{a_n}-1}{\ln{n}}$$

I've tried with no success so far to find some series $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ with the above conditions for which $B$ is convergent.

An answer to this question would be an interesting extension to the answer that, with the aid of Kelenner, I've given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076909/show-that-series-converge-or-diverge/1076929#1076929).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following appears to be a counterexample:

$a_n = \dfrac{1}{\ln(n)}$ if $n = 2^{k^2}$ for $k\in\mathbb N$, and $a_n=\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ otherwise.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! +1.